How to Disable VERP
How does one go about to disable VERP?
A unique folder is created for each bounce message containing the bounce. The folder will have a name such as bounce_66df08d75885e802455708. So, you have a long list of folders. In the meantime, my software is watching the INBOX folder to mark messages bounced in order not to receive future e-mails. However, the bounce messages are not going into the INBOX.
How does one disable VERP or what could be a workaround
I'm running Postfix.
What is odd, is that I'm running two other VPSs and the bounces are going into the INBOX and I have set them up using the same procedure.
Thanks for any assistance.
